# How can I make this path bend in FontLab

Tags: vector, interface-design, fontlab-studio, bezier-curve

Currently learning FontLab Studio and I've encountered a problem with below situation:

[image]

Essentially I would like the path between the two cyan nodes to be a curve, but I can't add control points to them for some reason.

When I try adding a new node with the red circled add node tool they too are without bezier control points.

When I try just move the path between the cyan points, instead of creating the bezier control points the whole shape just moves (as illustrated in green).

Both cyan nodes are "Sharp" connection types.

Anybody got a clue why I can't make that path curved? Or how can I make it curved?

Answer (score 1):

The answer is simple as can be, yet a newbie might succumb to it: Hold down `alt` while dragging the line and curve points will appear.